# How to include class as a feature

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I am currently experimenting with the idea of including the class of a feature vector as a separate feature. My work is about preposition selection in learner language use. I want to train a classifier that, given a certain position of a sentence, uses relevant context features around that position to build vectors. The classifier detects if there should be a preposition or if it should remain empty. Some features include:

1. Neighbouring N-grams, where N={2,3}, at Part-Of-Speech and token-level
2. Neighbouring nouns and verbs

The class expresses a binary distribution: 1 for preposition **presence** and 0 for preposition **absence**.

Consider that if a language learner opted to select a preposition in a given sentence, but the classifier thinks there should **NOT** be one, it can be interpreted as the classifier marking a language error: The learner inserted a preposition in a prohibited context. Conversely, if a learner did **NOT** use a preposition at a given position in a sentence, but the classifier does expect one, it is also an error.

The model is trained on correct negative (no preposition) and positive ("yes" preposition) *events* (context features around a certain position: a whitespace or a preposition). This means that the assigned labels are the gold standard, similarly for the test data, because they are trained on *native *language use which is assumed to be error-free. The same assumption cannot be made when running the classifier on learner's language - after all, learners make mistakes, which is what I am trying to detect.

I want to include the decision (yes/no) of the learner into the classifier rather than just as the assigned label. Because in practice, the chance on either error is very small, so the classifier should be very confident before marking it as such. But when I do this, the classifier always selects the value of that **decision feature** as the class. After all, it is trained so that there is a 100% correlation between said feature and the assigned class.

How do I turn this learner's decision - which is NOT an absolute indication of the actual answer - into an **indication** instead?

I'm experimenting with Linear Support Vector Classifier and Logistic/Linear Regression.

Thanks a bunch, if more details are needed, please ask.

Comment: Machine learning classification algorithms are designed to seek features that usefully predict the  instances class, as you note a highly predictive feature is a very attractive target for them.  You might make more progress if you had training and test data which had a significant percentage of language learner decisions which differed from the true class of the sentence, forcing the classifier to look elsewhere for discriminative information.  The logical conclusion of this process is to remove the  learner decision from the features, which places you back at the start. Maybe combine both?

Comment: Unfortunately, the learner data is not annotated so I have no knowledge of their errors as of now. I could manually add a bias towards the existing class with probabilty (so if initial guess + 0.5 >0.95 or something, then assign the error), but it is more elegant if the classifier does all this implicitly.

Comment: I may be a little confused, I thought you had the learner decision and had included it, but I may have misunderstood ?

Comment: I do, but the 'true class' is not known, so the differences between those cannot be included unfortunately.

Comment: So you have two sets of data, labelled sentences, not from language learners and unlabelled data from language learners ?

Comment: That is correct! I train on the labelled ones, and I evaluate shortly on those as well, but the actual data it is created for, is the unlabelled data.